# WebClient - adding defaultHeaders

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, webclient, spring-webflux

I'm trying to put multiple headers into defaultHeaders(), But I don't have idea how to create Consumer object from return of createHeaders() method

```
this.someWebClient = WebClient.builder()
        .baseUrl(someConfiguration.getApiUrl())
        .clientConnector(buildTimeoutConnector())
        .defaultHeaders(????) // Consumer<HttpHeaders>
        .build();
```

I can build my header in that way:

```
private HttpHeaders createHeaders(String token) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, V1_PUBLIC);
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.HOST, "abc");
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + token);
    return headers;
}
```

but how to wrap it into Consumer?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Clearly the method doc says that it needs a `Consumer` of some Type. So you can **create an anonymous class implementing the `Consumer` interface** or **use lambda expression like this**:

1. Using anonymous inner class:

```
this.someWebClient = WebClient.builder()
        .baseUrl(someConfiguration.getApiUrl())
        .clientConnector(buildTimeoutConnector())
        .defaultHeaders(new Consumer<HttpHeaders>() {
          @Override
          public void accept(HttpHeaders httpHeaders) {
            httpHeaders.addAll(createHeaders(token));
          }
        })
        .build();
```

2. Using lambda:

```
this.someWebClient = WebClient.builder()
        .baseUrl(someConfiguration.getApiUrl())
        .clientConnector(buildTimeoutConnector())
        .defaultHeaders(httpHeaders -> {
          httpHeaders.addAll(createHeaders(token));
        })
        .build();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private void addDefaultHeaders(final HttpHeaders headers) {
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "application/json");
  }
```

and then

```
this.someWebClient = WebClient.builder()
        .baseUrl(someConfiguration.getApiUrl())
        .clientConnector(buildTimeoutConnector())
        .defaultHeaders(this::addDefaultHeaders)
        .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this.

```
    @Bean
    public WebClient webClientConfiguration() {
        return WebClient
                .builder()
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create()
                        .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, connectionTimeout)
                        .responseTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(responseTimeout))
                ))
                .baseUrl(this.msConfigProperties.getApiUrl())
                .defaultHeaders(httpHeaders())
                .build();
    }
```

Then Consumer function

```
    private Consumer<HttpHeaders> httpHeaders(){
        return headers -> {
            headers.set(HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE, String.valueOf(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            headers.setBasicAuth(this.msConfigProperties.getUserName(),this.msConfigProperties.getPassword());
            headers.set(HEADER_ACCEPT_ENCODING, String.valueOf(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        };
    }
```